# Raspi Config on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: gpio, display, ubuntu, tutorial

I installed the Raspberry Pi2 image of Ubuntu Server 14.04 on my Raspberry Pi 2 B. The other day I bought a [LCD display](http://www.ebay.com/itm/LT-3-5-320-480-TFT-LCD-Display-Touch-Screen-for-Raspberry-Pi-B-B-PI2-/262070171454?hash=item3d0499773e), that is now plugged onto the GPIO pins: Is there any possibility to get raspi-config on Ubuntu?

I want to enable SPI like it is done in this [tutorial](http://www.circuitbasics.com/setup-lcd-touchscreen-raspberry-pi/) (I didn't found a good source on how to install the mentioned display on a Ubuntu running on a RPi2...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems you have to overcome. Even if you could install `raspi-config` it would not work.

The recent Raspbian use `Device Tree` to configure peripherals, and `raspi-config` uses this (which is one reason it is only in recent versions of `raspi-config`). AFAIK the current Ubuntu (15.10) also does, but not 14.04.

You would have to go back to an older tutorial which describes the manual process for configuring `SPI`.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu does not support raspi-config that is a Raspbian feature. You may be able to research the modules that are loaded by raspi-config to enable SPI and recreate that on Ubuntu (no guarantees though). I think the better course is to switch to Raspbian, as you already discovered most tutorials are written for it.

Comment: Installing Raspbian and following one of the tutorials seems to be my fallback variant. I would love to stick to my configured Ubuntu (+ I am more familiar with Ubuntu). I just want to have a shell output on the LCD screen I bought. However, thanks for your quick answer! Maybe someone else has 2cents :)